# Vertical Centre Text in DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using hosted shopping cart software which means I have limitations on what I can do with HTML (I can't edit HTML but can add new CSS styles and JavaScript).

What I am trying to is vertically align the Link Text below (remember that the HTML is hard coded):

```
<div id="ct_sc_listing">
<div class="ct_sc_listing_cat">
<div class="ct_sc_listing_cat_name"><a href="#">Link Text</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code I'm using:

```
<style type="text/css">

#ct_sc_listing 
    {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }

.ct_sc_listing_cat {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #336;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #DFEBEB;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.ct_sc_listing_cat a:link {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #006;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none; /* No underlines on the link */
    z-index: 10; /* Places the link above everything else in the div */

}

.ct_sc_listing_cat:visited, .ct_sc_listing_cat a:visited {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #006;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ct_sc_listing_cat:hover, .ct_sc_listing_cat:hover a{
    background-color: #006;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #DFEBEB;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
.ct_sc_listing_cat:active, .ct_sc_listing_cat a:active {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 24px;
}

</style>
```

Is there anyway, using CSS or JavaScript, that I can align the text vertically?

**EDIT: I should add that the line height method won't work because the Link Text is dynamic and might span one or 2 lines**

I have had an idea that it may be possible to enclose the Link Text in a DIV using JavaScript and then use CSS to style and vertically align the text. I have no idea how to do that though, so any ideas would be welcome!

I know it seems like a lot of CSS code but I have set up the link so that the DIV is clickable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net with these details?  Would make it much easier to visualise and edit!

Comment: Sure - http://jsfiddle.net/6kZE2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6kZE2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great article that talks about one of the best ways to vertically align text via css:

http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: I've managed to get this to work using Andrew's method [link]http://jsfiddle.net/6kZE2/2/[link] but now the div is no longer clickable (only the text is). Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The only way to make a div clickable is to wrap it in an anchor tag itself.

I think what you're trying to do here is style the link so that it should look a certain way, but also be clickable.  If that is the case than you should take a different approach to this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SDC6z/

This should work much better than what you already have set up.

Remember, if you're using the same styles/fonts on link, as you are link:hover, you only have to put it once.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at he CSS property `display:table` and `vertical-align:middle`. Also, you're repeating a lot of your style declarations...for example, the font-family declaration only needs to be written in the `.ct_sc_listing_cat` class.